# Windows 8 ListBox Databinding

Tags: data-binding, windows-8, listbox

I have a listbox I'm trying to databind to with a "metro" app.  Here is my xaml:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="ImagesList" Margin="40" Grid.Row="1">
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And I've created a source:

```
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> items = 
            new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "a"));
        items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b", "b"));
        items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("c", "c"));
        this.ImagesList.ItemsSource = items;
```

I'd expect this to create a list of text in my app a, b and c

However instead I'm getting the following text for each element I've bound:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.CLRKeyBaluePairOmpl'2[System.String, System.String]
```

It looks like it's displaying the fullname of the type I'm binding... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a `Converter` to the `Binding`.

cerate converter as XAML resource

```
<src:KeyValueConverter:Key="KeyConverter"/>
```

Add binding converter to the text source

```
Text="{Binding Path=ItemsList, Converter={StaticResource KeyConverter}}"
```

sample converter code

```
public class KeyValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var kvp = (KeyValuePair)value;
        return kvp.Key;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the <src element go in the xaml?

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because I believe it works for my KVP example.

Answer (score 0):

My Xaml was also wrong it should have been:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ImagesList" Margin="40" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```